# which encryption algorithm to use for sending encrypted data from android apk to remote server vice versa

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I need to connect to a web service on a remote server, and need to pass all parameters in encrypted form for method calls, and the response from the server needs to be in encrypted form as well.

```
APK  ----->encrypted input parameters for method calling ---->remote server
Remote Server ------>decrypt the input parameters and response with same encrpted alg.
```

The point is I want to use one key (symmetric encryption) for encryption and decryption.
Please let me know which code to use for that in android so that it will work correctly in both APK and REMOTE SERVER (Which is Java web service).

```
frankly speaking, I have used some algorithms such as DES;
```

`but don't know why sometimes what is encrypted at APK side is not decrypted at REMOTE
and null is returned!`

One more thing, I want you guys to comment on this: "In order to avoid forgery requests, I used one variable called ReqID at APK side with initial value of 1, and at remote server's web service side I also used a reqID in DB for that client. And with each request comming from APK the reqID is read and appended to a key (that is reqID+key) and used it for encrypting the input parameters of any desired method of the web service, and at server side by receiving that request, the last reqID for that client is read from the DB as well as the key, and used for decrypting the input parameters. And after this, the reqID is increased by one at server side, and at APK side as well to make them be synced. But the issue is sometimes the decrypt at SERVER side doesn't work and returns null and sometimes at APK side while decrypting it fails and return null! What is the solution?

Comment: This is not a website where you order code. People here help with concrete problems; not with "which code to use". In addition to that, your last paragraph is absolutely not readable. Please take the time and break it down into short sentences. Subject, verb, object. Otherwise, you will only receive downvotes. You expect other people to spend their time to help you so show some respect and make that as easy as possible iInstead of dumping a 5 lines sentence at us with no meaningful boundaries between the various sections

Comment: I changed the last paragraph.

Comment: @chrylis Do I need to change my code at APK for using HTTPS?

Comment: Do not use DES, it is no longer secure, use AES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTTPS, there is no need to add any additional encryption.

On the server use TLS 1.2 and Perfect Forward Secrecy. Everything will be encrypted including the query parameters. But the query parameters may be caught in server logs so it is best to send sensitive information as a POST.

Pin the server certificate in the app to prevent MITM attacks.

Comment: I am using IIS as my web server at server, and using JSON kind of call, dont know whether you know ashx handler or not, but I have used this handler at SERVER which returns JSON as response. Do I need to send POST in this case too?

Comment: The issue is that some systems (servers) will log the full URL including any query string so do not put sensitive information in the querry string. This is the same for HTTP and HTTPS.